# Use paracol to simulate a longtable?

Tags: tables, multicol

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol,lipsum,calc}
\begin{document}

\setlength\columnseprule{.4pt}
\setcolumnwidth{0pt,.55\textwidth,.4\textwidth,0pt}

Add Title

\begin{paracol}{4}

\raisebox{1em}{\hspace{-1em}\rule{\textwidth-1em}{.4pt}}

\switchcolumn aaa \switchcolumn\lipsum[2]\switchcolumn\switchcolumn*

\hspace{-2em}\rule{\textwidth}{.4pt}

\switchcolumn aaa \switchcolumn \lipsum[2]\switchcolumn\switchcolumn*

\switchcolumn aaa \switchcolumn \lipsum[2]\switchcolumn\switchcolumn*

\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

1. The toprule (use \raisebox...) is slightly lower, but if comment out ``Add Title''  then all right, how to fix it?
2. How to accurately control \hspace{-1em} and rule{textwidth-1em} (1em was guessed) to fit the vetical rule ?
3. How to force add bottomrule at firstpage and toprule at second page (There is a paragraph across two pages）？

Comment: To add another issue with your code: 4) The second horizontal rule is too low to separate the first from the second row.

Comment: Regarding 3: I would pesonally not add a horizontal line at the end of the table on the first paga as the row continues on the next page. If there was a line, one might think that the corresponding row is already finnished.

Comment: Some general questions: Does the left column in your real document also contain almost no text while the second column contains very long texts? If this is the case, you might consider using different widths for the 2 columns. Apart from that, you might also want to use a table completely without vertical or horizontal lines but with some white space to guide the eye instead.

Comment: I take it you want to split paragraphs across pages, which longtable doesn't do.  BTW, \rule has an optional argument to raise/lower it relative to the baseline, if you exceed the limits of a column you should use \leavevmode\rlap{}, tabular uses \hspace{\tabcolsep} at the edges of a column (2\tabcolsep total between columns),  you can use the afterpage package to add rule at the top of each page, but the bottom rule is trickier.  Perhaps a bottom float?

Comment: It might be easier just to split paragraphs using saveboxes and \vsplit and use longttable for everything else.